# WordPress theme functions.php $wpdb->insert create duplicates

Tags: php, wordpress, wordpress-theming

I'm creating a custom theme for WordPress with parsed reviews from Google Maps and Yelp services on a front page. I made two functions in **functions.php** file to create a **reviews table** and fill the data from **reviews.json** file, but when I switch my WordPress theme I noticed that all those reviews got duplicated or even quadruplicated.

```
function create_reviews_db_table() {
  
  global $wpdb;
  
  $reviews_table = $wpdb->prefix . "theme_reviews";

  if($wpdb->get_var("SHOW TABLES LIKE '$reviews_table'") != $reviews_table) {
    $sql = "CREATE TABLE $reviews_table (
      id int NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
      review_type varchar(10) NOT NULL,
      author varchar(50) NOT NULL,
      author_avatar_url varchar(255) NOT NULL,
      review_date DATE NOT NULL,
      review_text TEXT DEFAULT NULL,
      review_rating int NOT NULL
      ) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4;";
    dbDelta( $sql );

  }

}

function fill_reviews_table_with_data() {

  global $wpdb;

  $reviews_table = $wpdb->prefix . "theme_reviews";

  if($wpdb->get_var("SELECT * FROM '$reviews_table'") == 0) {
    $reviews_json = file_get_contents(__DIR__ . '/assets/reviews/reviews.json');

    $decoded_json = json_decode($reviews_json, false);

    foreach( $decoded_json->reviews as $value ) {
      $wpdb->insert($reviews_table, array(
        'review_type'       => $value->type,
        'author'            => $value->author,
        'author_avatar_url' => $value->author_avatar,
        'review_date'       => $value->date,
        'review_text'       => $value->text,
        'review_rating'     => (int)$value->rating
      ));
    }
  }

}

add_action("after_setup_theme", 'create_reviews_db_table');
add_action("after_setup_theme", "fill_reviews_table_with_data");


MySQL 8.0.25 & PHP 8.0.7
```

What I'm doing wrong?

Comment: It calls your function every page load. Use a cron instead.

Comment: @HowardE that's true, seems like 'after_setup_theme' hook doing absolutely different thing than I thought. Thank you!
You can post an answer and I'll mark it.

Comment: How often do you want this to execute?

Comment: @HowardE, once theme is installed or switched back to this theme.
I think I found the correct hook: 
"after_switch_theme"

What do you think?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you should do this all in one function, so that it just fires, creates the table, and pulls the data in one 'swoop' - also when it's done, if you activate/re-activate the theme... if the table exists, then the data should be there.

I mean, you could add a simple `if !($wpdb->get_row("SELECT * from $reviews_table WHERE id = '1';"))` to make sure there is data in the table.

Also, I think this is the hook you're looking for https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/switch_theme/ which is more like a plugin activation script, but for themes.

```
<?php
function create_reviews_db_table() {

    global $wpdb;

    $reviews_table = $wpdb->prefix . "theme_reviews";
    
    $sql = "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS $reviews_table (
      id int NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
      review_type varchar(10) NOT NULL,
      author varchar(50) NOT NULL,
      author_avatar_url varchar(255) NOT NULL,
      review_date DATE NOT NULL,
      review_text TEXT DEFAULT NULL,
      review_rating int NOT NULL
      ) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4;";
        dbDelta( $sql );

    if (null === $wpdb->get_row("SELECT * from $reviews_table WHERE id = '1';")){
        $reviews_json = file_get_contents( __DIR__ . '/assets/reviews/reviews.json' );

        $decoded_json = json_decode( $reviews_json, false );

        foreach ( $decoded_json->reviews as $value ) {
            $wpdb->insert( $reviews_table, array(
                'review_type'       => $value->type,
                'author'            => $value->author,
                'author_avatar_url' => $value->author_avatar,
                'review_date'       => $value->date,
                'review_text'       => $value->text,
                'review_rating'     => (int)$value->rating
            ) );
        }
    }
}
add_action( "switch_theme", 'create_reviews_db_table' );
```

Comment: Thank you! Marked as answered.

Comment: I hope this does what you wanted.  You can upvote it as well if you like.

Comment: Will do that when my reputation would be higher, I only can do that from 15 points or higher.